# Iteratively list Drupal form titles

Tags: php, drupal, forms, foreach

I am trying to list all `#titles` in a Drupal form module; however, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
foreach ($form_values as $key => $value) {
   echo $form['myForm'][$key]['#title'];
}
```

The method above does not return anything. I can list the `$key` values by doing the following:

```
foreach (...) {
   echo $key . ' ';
}
```

but I can't find a way to list the titles (e.g., `'#title' => t('Name')`) for each form input.

Any help? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your request a bit baffles me, but

```
function print_title($form) {
  foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
    print_title($form[$key]);
  }
  if (isset($form['#title'])) {
    // do something with your title
  }
}
```